# Div hide/show toggle issue

Tags: javascript, html, css, hide, show

I'm currently making an iphone webapp and have almost finished it, I just need to fix this one little issue im having

Ive managed to hide one div layer and show another, but what I would like is for the same button to then show the layer I have hid and hide the one that I have shown when clicked again. So basically clicking the button would take it back to the original state

the code I am currently using is

```
<script type="text/javascript">


function toggle_layout(d)
{
    var onediv = document.getElementById(d);
    var divs=['Posts','Posts2'];

    for (var i=0;i<divs.length;i++)
    {
        if (onediv != document.getElementById(divs[i]))
        {
            document.getElementById(divs[i]).style.display='none';
        }
    }

    onediv.style.display = 'block';
}


</script>
```

It hides a div I have named "Posts" and shows a div I have named "Posts2", but clicking it again does not reverse the effect.

If you wanna take a look at my site its http://a-m-creativecapture.tumblr.com/
Will have to view it on a mobile to see what I am talking about.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried style.visibility (visible|hidden) instead of style.display?

Comment: Im not very good with javascript at all, I literally copied this from another answer I had seen and changed the names to apply to mine. Could you please show me what you mean

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your divs are something like this:

```
<div id="posts"></div>
<div id="posts2"></div>
```

You can use the following code:

```
var posts = document.getElementById('posts'),
    posts2 = document.getElementById('posts2');

function toggle() {
    if (this == posts) {
        posts.style.display = 'none';
        posts2.style.display = 'block';
    } else {
        posts.style.display = 'block';
        posts2.style.display = 'none';
    }
}

div1.onclick = toggle;
div2.onclick = toggle;
```